# How can I disable the auto-rotation of img in html according to landscape-portrait info in metadata?

Tags: java, html, image, metadata, landscape-portrait

I have photos which are taken with iPhone. Therefore they have landscape-portrait info in their metadata. These photos are saved such that they are in correct rotation when opened with mspaint for instance. The problem occurs when we use these images in a website. The images in website can be viewed from iPhone without any problem. However chrome browser in my laptop uses these metadata and tries to correct the rotation once again. Since we already handle that a portrait photo is viewed as rotated left. 
How can I disable the auto-rotation of img in html according to landscape-portrait info in metadata?
By the way if I use a photo which does not have any metadata info webpage can be viewed both in iPhone and chrome without any problem.

Comment: My guess is it's impossible.

Comment: the way i worked around it is that on file upload, i constructed a new image only using the data from the temporary image, which excludes any metadata from the original. this is assuming u use PHP to upload the picture.

Comment: I use jsp but I think I can do that if there is no other way

Comment: its simple and clean for me, only 2 lines of code. i doubt you'll find a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very clean way to solve this.
Install ImageMagick and use command line:

`mogrify -strip yourpicture.jpg`

and that will erase exif information.

If you have more pictures, then run:

```
for i in *.jpg; do
    mogrify -strip $i
done
```